# matlab bar3 diagram higher bars

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, handle, matlab-figure

I habe a problem with bar3 diagram. I want to change the design of the bars and tried it with axis handle, but I could not solve the problem yet.

I want bars which are thinner and longer. Additionally the bars should have quadratic base areas.

Thank you very much in anticipation!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `bar3(..., width)`, where `width` is normalized bar width between 0 and 1. See [`bar3` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html).

The bars have a square base. If it doesn't look so, that's because of different axis scales. To solve it use `axis equal`.

Example:

```
bar3(1:3, ones(3,5), .2)
axis equal
```

[image]